# How to sanitise and store a decimal in sql databse

Tags: php, html, sql

I am new to sql and php but I am trying to figure out how I can safely store a decimal value that I take from an HTML form, sanitise it in php and then send it to an sql database. Currently, I am casting the HTML value to a float and using FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT for my sanitizing. The sql data value type is decimal(10,5). But when I store -2.5 into the database it comes out as -25.00000000. I know most of my code is right because when I take other values from the same form, sanitise them and then enter them into the databse it works fine.

```
    $Goal_howmch = (float) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'How_much', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    
    <label for="How much"><b>How much: </b></label>
                    <select name="How_much" id="How much" default="0" required>
                        <option value=-10>-10%</option>
                        <option value=-7.5>-7.5%</option>
                        <option value=-5>-5%</option>
                        <option value=-2.5>-2.5%</option>
                        <option value=0 selected>0%</option>
                        <option value=2.5>2.5%</option>
                        <option value=5>5%</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear as it's mixing html with PHP. The first thing you  need to figure out is at what point that error is happening.  For example, on the line after you set $Goal_howmch you should do a `echo $Goal_howmch;`. If that looks fine, determine what it is just before you send it from your web browser. If that is fine, check what it is when your PHP script receives it. Next, check what happens if you hardcode -2.5 in your PHP code and send that to your database. Lastly, use your DB directly and try inserting that value with an `insert` statement. You now know the place of error.

Comment: Also, are you making any other calculations on this value in your code. I notice you have it listed as a percent. Maybe you are doing something in that regards as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's specifically mentioned in the above documentation, because many seem to find this unintuitive it's worth pointing out that FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT will remove the decimal character unless you specify FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION:

```
<?php
$number_string = '12.34';

echo filter_var( $number_string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT ); // 1234

echo filter_var( $number_string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ); // 12.34
?>
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php#125563